# Makefile not giving the expected compilation results

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile, g++

I am quite new to Make. I am attempting to write a Makefile to build a medium-sized Linux C/C++ application as below.

Making a simple Makefile by having all source files in one location and explicitly listing the source files works ok for me but I would like it to be more generic.

I have all my source files (C and C++) in the `src` folder in different subdirectories. I have header files inside an `inc` and `inc/common` folder, and then libs inside a `lib` folder.

The Makefile is run on the same level :

```
SRC_DIR := src
OBJ_DIR := obj
BIN_DIR := bin

CXX := /bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++

EXE := $(BIN_DIR)/runfile
SRC := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name *.cpp -or -name *.c)   
OBJ := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%,$(OBJ_DIR)/%,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SRC))))

CPPFLAGS := -Iinc -Iinc/common -MMD -MP
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall
LDFLAGS  := -Llib
LDLIBS   := 

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ) | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC) | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    
$(BIN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    @$(RM) -rv $(BIN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR)

-include $(OBJ:.o=.d)
```

I get lots of errors such as below when I run it, including problems opening dependency files.  I think i'm almost there, but can't see my error exactly :

```
compilation terminated.
/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Iinc -Iinc/common -MMD -MP -std=c++11 -Wall -c -o obj/main.d.o
cc -Llib  obj/main.d.o   -o obj/main.d
/usr/bin/ld: obj/main.d.o: relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/usr/bin/ld: obj/main.d.o: relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/usr/bin/ld: obj/main.d.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
```

Comment: consider using https://github.com/cppfw/prorab it will simplify your `makefile` a lot and make it generic as you want

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how the output you show can be generated from the makefile you show here but anyway.

This is not right:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC) | $(OBJ_DIR)
```

A pattern rule is a template that tells make "if you want to build a target that matches this pattern, then you can build it from the prerequisites that match this pattern".

Here you are listing ALL your source files as a prerequisite for EVERY object file.  Suppose `SRC` is set to `foo.c bar.c biz.c baz.c`, then this expands to:

```
obj/%.o : foo.c bar.c biz.c baz.c | obj
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

You're telling make that every single `.o` target depends on **ALL** the source files, not just the one for that object file.  Further, the automatic variable `$<` always expands to the *first* prerequisite, which here will always be `foo.c`.  So, you're compiling `foo.c` four times, creating each of the object files.

The very first important rule when debugging makefiles is to look carefully at the output (command lines) that make prints.  If they are not right, then your makefile is not right.  If you do that you'll see all the compile lines are compiling the same source, like:

```
g++ -c foo.c -o obj/foo.o
g++ -c foo.c -o obj/bar.o
g++ -c foo.c -o obj/biz.o
g++ -c foo.c -o obj/baz.o
```

That clearly cannot work and it's why you get link errors trying to link together all these object files: they all have the same content.

You need this:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

which tells make how to build an object file from a *single* source file.

You also need to create the actual output directory that the object file will go into.  Just creating `$(OBJ_DIR)` is not enough, if the object file appears in a subdirectory.